# Callback and Co-routine on AWS SDK

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am building an app which is using AWS mobile Client SDK but I would like to use coroutine but I have an issue as the SDK from AWS is using Callback.

```
override suspend fun login(username: String, password: String): ResultResponse<SignInResult> {
        AWSMobileClient.getInstance()
            .signIn(username, password, null, object : Callback<SignInResult> {
                override fun onResult(signInResult: SignInResult) {
                    ResultResponse.Success(signInResult)
                }
                override fun onError(e: Exception?) {
                    if (e != null) {
                        ResultResponse.Error(e)
                    }
                }
            })
    }
```

Any idea how to workaround this or do it properly ?

Regards

Comment: What SDK are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Asynchronous callbacks can be converted into synchronous suspend functions using either `suspendCoroutine()` or `suspendCancellableCoroutine()`. Typically you would create a suspend extension function version of the corresponding asynchronous call so you can use it anywhere you would normally use the SDK call (rather than using `suspendCoroutine` at each location, since it is somewhat clumsy).

`suspendCancellableCoroutine` is used when the API call provides a way to cancel it early. If that's the case, you can make your suspend function support coroutine cancellation, so the API call is automatically cancelled if the associated coroutine is cancelled. Exactly what you want since on Android, `lifecycleScope` and `viewModelScope` automatically cancel their coroutines when their associated lifecycles are over.

I don't know what version of AWS SDK you're using, but here's approximately how you what your suspend function would look like:

```
suspend fun AWSMobileClient.signIn(userName: String, password: String, someParam: Any?): SignInResult = suspendCoroutine { continuation ->
    signIn(userName, password, someParam, object : Callback<SignInResult> {
        override fun onResult(signInResult: SignInResult) {
            continuation.resume(signInResult)
        }
        override fun onError(e: Exception) {
            continuation.resumeWithException(e)
        }
    })
}
```

I don't know the type of that third parameter so I just put `Any?`.

And now your existing function would become:

```
override suspend fun login(username: String, password: String): ResultResponse<SignInResult> {
    return try {
        val signInResult = AWSMobileClient.getInstance().signIn(username, password, null)
        ResultResponse.Success(signInResult)
    } catch(e: Exception) {
        ResultResponse.Error(e)
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if `ResultResponse` is your own class. In case it is, be aware the Kotlin standard library already contains a Result class, which would make this function simpler with the use of `runCatching`:

```
override suspend fun login(username: String, password: String): Result<SignInResult> {
    return runCatching {
        AWSMobileClient.getInstance().signIn(username, password, null)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to convert callback-based APIs to suspending functions is to use [suspendCoroutine](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.coroutines/suspend-coroutine.html) or [suspendCancellableCoroutine](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/suspend-cancellable-coroutine.html) (if the callback API is cancellable).

In your case, it will look something like this:

```kotlin
override suspend fun login(username: String, password: String): SignInResult {
    return suspendCoroutine { cont ->
        AWSMobileClient.getInstance()
            .signIn(username, password, null, object : Callback<SignInResult> {
                override fun onResult(signInResult: SignInResult) {
                    cont.resume(signInResult)
                }
                override fun onError(e: Exception?) {
                    if (e != null) {
                        cont.resumeWithException(e)
                    }
                }
            })
    }
}
```

This suspends the current coroutine until the callback is called with the result or an error. Note that the `login()` method will throw an exception if `onError` is called (which is usually what you want when using suspend functions).

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using this SDK

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-android/

If you want to use an AWS SDK that supports Kotlin features likes coroutines, use the new **AWS SDK for Kotlin**.

[Setting up the AWS SDK for Kotlin](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-kotlin/latest/developer-guide/setup.html)